# What's the name for this kind of 2-categorical unsymmetric pullback?

Tags: universal-property, 2-categories, pullback

What is the name for this weak version of a 2-categorical pullback?

The solid square commutes up to a not necessarily invertible 2-morphism  $\eta$ and has the following universal property: For any square $(P', \tilde f, \tilde g, \tilde \eta)$ as indicated in the diagram, where $\tilde \eta : g \circ \tilde f \Rightarrow f \circ \tilde g$, the 1-category of "comparison data" has a terminal object.

The objects of this category are tuples $(h,\alpha,\beta)$ consisting of a morphism $h : P' \to P$, a 2-morphism $\alpha : \tilde f \Rightarrow f' \circ h$, and a 2-morphism $\beta : g' \circ h \Rightarrow \tilde g$ such that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism (but $\beta$ might not) and such that $\tilde\eta = \beta \circ (\eta h) \circ \alpha$.

*Motivation:* The topos of sheaves on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is the pullback of $\mathrm{Set}$ and $\mathrm{Set}[\mathrm{LocRing}]$ over $\mathrm{Set}[\mathrm{Ring}]$ in the 2-category of toposes in this sense, as [detailed over at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255511/the-philosophy-behind-local-rings).

[image]

Comment: Does assuming $\alpha$ invertible give a weaker universal property than in general? I would rather define the morphisms of such cones using $\alpha^{-1}$, then it looks like a special case of some kind of op-lax thing. Also, have you considered asking on the categories mailing list? Someone there would surely know the answer.